# Previewing RestructuredText with firefox while editing in vim

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use vim to edit restructured tex and see the result in the firefox. I found this posting http://www.zopyx.com/blog/editing-restructuredtext-with-vim which shows the way. It works but every time it opens a new instance of firefox. I want it to open only one instance of it  not several tabs of it.

Here is the code:

:com RP :exec "Vst html" | w! /tmp/test.html | :q | !firefox /tmp/test.html

Could you help me to change the above code to achieve what I want.

thanks,
Ahmet

Answer (score 1):

Enter *about-config* in the address bar and write *newwindow* in the Filter bar.
Set the **browser.link.open_newwindow** value to **1**.
Now Firefox will open /tmp/test.html in the last visited tab.